# Request multiple tracking numbers with Fedex API

Tags: c#, asp.net, fedex

I'm making a web app, for tracking Fedex shipments, I currently have about 10,000-15,000 packages daily.
I integrated Fedex Api in my System but it takes more tan 20 minutes to get the status of only 1300 packages. Is there a Way to make this faster? I read that you can send 30 packages in one request but can't find a Way to make it work.

Here is a link to another question, that I found but didn't get it to work

[Requesting many tracking numbers with Fedex SOAP API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665544/requesting-many-tracking-numbers-with-fedex-soap-api-with-php/47297431?noredirect=1#comment81546286_47297431)

CODE

```
{

TrackRequest request = new TrackRequest();

        request.WebAuthenticationDetail = new WebAuthenticationDetail();
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential = new WebAuthenticationCredential();
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential.Key = ""; // Replace "XXX" with the Key
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential.Password = ""; // Replace "XXX" with the Password
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.ParentCredential = new WebAuthenticationCredential();
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.ParentCredential.Key = ""; // Replace "XXX" with the Key
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.ParentCredential.Password = ""; // Replace "XXX"
        request.ClientDetail = new ClientDetail();
        request.ClientDetail.AccountNumber = ""; // Replace "XXX" with the client's account number
        request.ClientDetail.MeterNumber = ""; // Replace "XXX" with the client's meter number
        request.TransactionDetail = new TransactionDetail();
        request.TransactionDetail.CustomerTransactionId = "***Track Request using VC#***";  //This is a reference field for the customer.  Any value can be used and will be provided in the response.
        request.Version = new VersionId();

        // Tracking information
        request.SelectionDetails = new TrackSelectionDetail[1] { new TrackSelectionDetail() };

        request.SelectionDetails[0].PackageIdentifier = new TrackPackageIdentifier();
        request.SelectionDetails[0].PackageIdentifier.Value = TrackNumberGlobal; //"787883551221" Replace "XXX" with tracking number or door tag
        request.SelectionDetails[0].PackageIdentifier.Type = TrackIdentifierType.TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG;
        request.ProcessingOptions = new TrackRequestProcessingOptionType[1];
        request.ProcessingOptions[0] = TrackRequestProcessingOptionType.INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS;

        return request;

}

private void TrackReplyy(TrackReply reply)
    {
        foreach (CompletedTrackDetail completedTrackDetail in       reply.CompletedTrackDetails)
        {
            foreach (TrackDetail trackDetail in completedTrackDetail.TrackDetails)
            {
                SqlCommand cos = new SqlCommand();
                cos.CommandText = "Update estatus_fedex SET estadofedex = @estado WHERE fedextracking = @track";
                cos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", trackDetail.StatusDetail.Description);
                cos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@track", TrackNumberGlobal);
                cos.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cos.Connection = sqlConn;
                cos.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (trackDetail.Events != null)
                {
                    foreach (TrackEvent trackevent in trackDetail.Events)
                    {   
                        if(trackevent.StatusExceptionCode != null)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                            cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE estatus_fedex SET ExcpetionCode = @codigo WHERE fedextracking = @param2";
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", trackevent.StatusExceptionCode);
                            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", TrackNumberGlobal);
                            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd2.Connection = sqlConn;
                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            if (trackevent.TimestampSpecified)
                            {
                                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
                                insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EstatusFedexHistorial(FedexTracking,EstadoFedex_Hist,ExceptionCode_Hist,Tiempo_Hist,EventDescription) VALUES (@Track,@Estado,@Excepcion,@Tiempo,@Evento)";
                                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Track", TrackNumberGlobal);
                                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", trackDetail.StatusDetail.Description);
                                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Excepcion", trackevent.StatusExceptionCode);
                                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tiempo", trackevent.Timestamp);
                                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evento", trackevent.EventDescription);
                                insert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                insert.Connection = sqlConn;
                                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (trackevent.TimestampSpecified)
                            {
                                SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand();
                                sqlc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EstatusFedexHistorial(FedexTracking,EstadoFedex_Hist,Tiempo_Hist,EventDescription) VALUES (@Track,@Estado,@Tiempo,@Evento)";
                                sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Track", TrackNumberGlobal);
                                sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", trackDetail.StatusDetail.Description);
                                sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tiempo", trackevent.Timestamp);
                                sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evento", trackevent.EventDescription);
                                sqlc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                sqlc.Connection = sqlConn;
                                sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE EstatusFedexHistorial SET Manifiesto = @manifiesto WHERE FedexTracking = @track";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manifiesto", manifiesto);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@track", TrackNumberGlobal);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you “read that you can send 30 packages in one request” and what did you try that you couldn't make work?

Comment: I was told by people that work in Fedex, they sent me Code but I can't work with that since it is in XML. In the question, i posted a link, that has a comment with Code but didm't work

Comment: The link you posted says “you need to send each track as a separate request” so that contradicts what you “read”. Since you won't post your code you will have to ask “people that work in Fedex”.

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987850/8099148

Comment: Mmmm i can post my Code, but I taught it would be not worth it

Comment: Perhaps they're speaking of the multiple tracking numbers GET requests on their website, such as https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=XXX,YYY,ZZZ&cntry_code=us&locale=en_US which can support up to 30. Did you consider just using cURL or something to scrape/parse that response?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like the following code where trackingNumbers is an array of tracking numbers.

```
request.SelectionDetails = new TrackSelectionDetail[trackingNumbers.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < trackingNumbers.Length; i++)
{
   request.SelectionDetails[i] = new TrackSelectionDetail()
   {
      PackageIdentifier = new TrackPackageIdentifier
      {
         Value = trackingNumbers[i],
         Type = TrackIdentifierType.TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks carlos. "TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG" was the enum value i was looking for !